# custom wordpress rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

I am trying custom rewrite for following url...

```
http://www.domain.com/lp/1
```

and it would be parsed using

```
lp.php?p=1
```

I have tried following...

```
add_action( 'init', 'aagt_rewrite_add_rewrites' );
function aagt_rewrite_add_rewrites()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^lp/(\d+)/?$', // p followed by a slash, a series of one or more digits and maybe another slash
        'lp.php?p=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

but if i try url( http://www.domain.com/lp/1) after above code, it didn't work. am i missing something, i have tried flushing htaccess rules. please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has two kinds of rewrite rules- internal and external. Internal rules are parsed by WordPress and routed to `index.php`. External rewrites get written to .htaccess and are not directed to WordPress.

Right now your rule is a mix between internal and external- you have it structured as an internal rule, but you have it incorrectly pointed to a file other than `index.php`.

If you want to use the WordPress environment within the code that receives this rewrite rule, it should be an internal rewrite. If you want this to be an external rule that is not processed by WordPress, then you need to change your rule to use `$1` instead of `$matches[1]`.

**EDIT**

here are a couple of methods, the first is the quick and dirty method -

## Method One

Step 1 for both methods is to add a query var `lpid` to WordPress array of recognized query vars:

```
function wpa55759_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'lpid';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa55759_query_vars' );
```

Step 2, add the rewrite rule to only set `lpid` when our rule is matched:

```
function wpa55759_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'lp/(\d+)/?$',
        'index.php?lpid=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa55759_rewrites' );
```

Step 3, hook `parse_request` and check if our query var is set. If so, load `lp.php` from the template directory, and exit:

```
function wpa55759_parse_request( $request ){
    if( isset( $request->query_vars['lpid'] ) ):
        include( get_template_directory() . "/lp.php" );
        exit();
    endif;
    return $request;
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpa55759_parse_request' );
```

To get the value of `lpid` inside `lp.php`:

```
global $wp;
echo $wp->query_vars['lpid'];
```

Basically we're checking for our query var and cutting out early. WordPress never runs a database query to load posts or pages. Not sure what side effects this may have otherwise.

## Method Two

The second method is to create a page within WordPress, `lp`, and point our rule at that, also passing the query var:

```
function wpa55759_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'lp/(\d+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=lp&lpid=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa55759_rewrites' );
```

Now you can create a template `page-lp.php` and access `lpid` with:

```
echo get_query_var( 'lpid' );
```

One additional option with this second method is to filter `template_redirect` and shortcut the template hierarchy, loading your own custom file:

```
function wpa55759_template_redirect(){
    global $wp_query;
    if( $wp_query->get( 'lpid' ) ):
        include( get_template_directory() . "/lp.php" );
        exit();
    endif;
}
add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'wpa55759_template_redirect' );
```

Comment: and where should i have lp.php file? inside template folder or at root? Even is there any easy way to achieve this? for example if i create a new page called /lp and then is it allowed by wordpress to access http://domain.com/lp/var1  can you please help me with how to get var1 in template for processing with php. thanks for great help.

Comment: @seoppc - see edit

Comment: @Milo, What if I wanted to output from a class instead of loading a template, but still need access to WordPress functions to pull data, etc? What should I hook instead of parse request?

Answer (score 0):

go to wp-admin/options-permalink.php

nothing to do but "Save Changes"

Comment: it didn't help, as i have tried already.

Comment: 'lp/(\d+)/?$',

where lp.php path?

Comment: inside theme folder, shout it be at root?

Comment: ya.. it should be at root : domain.com/lp.php

if you want to work inside your theme folder, you should add query var http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api

Comment: thanks for your help, 1 more question... would it affect wordpress permalinks if i use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} dj` http://domain.com/dj/   i want to use these links for google analytics campaign tracking purpose.